# How to select a row in a table view?

Tags: macos, nstableview

I have an macOS app developed in Xcode 11 and a tableView in the View. I would like to show a row as selected or change the background color the same as selected color when the user right clicks on a row. How can this be done?

I saw the following to deselect the row.
**tableView.deselectRow(row)** However I don't see how to simply select the row with the right click action code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the (a bit more complicated and a bit more powerful) method:

- (void)selectRowIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes byExtendingSelection:(BOOL)extend;

Example: (select only one single row **theRow** which should exist)

```
    NSIndexSet *selectionSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:theRow];
    [myTableView selectRowIndexes: selectionSet byExtendingSelection:NO];
```

Comment: So, I tried the following code:    let row = tableView.row(at: point)
        NSIndexSet *selectionSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:row]
        [tableView selectRowIndexes: selectionSet byExtendingSelection:NO] but I get several errors on the NSIndexSet. (like * is not a prefix unary operator, cannot find indeSetWithIndex in scope etc). How do I fix these errors?

Comment: let indexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
        indexSet.add(row)
        tableView.selectRowIndexes(indexSet as IndexSet, byExtendingSelection: true)
        let currentRow: NSTableRowView = tableView.rowView(atRow: row, makeIfNecessary: false)!
        currentRow.backgroundColor = .gray